# Two list of datetimeIndex, want one list of lists of pairwise strings of dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Currently I have the following

```
start_of_month_dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2021-01-01' , freq='1M')-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
end_of_month_dates = pd.date_range('2018-02-01', '2021-02-01' , freq='1M')-pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
```

which results in

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01',
               '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01',
               '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01',
               '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01',
               '2019-05-01', '2019-06-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-08-01',
               '2019-09-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-12-01',
               '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01',
               '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01',
               '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30',
               '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31',
               '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31',
               '2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30',
               '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-08-31',
               '2019-09-30', '2019-10-31', '2019-11-30', '2019-12-31',
               '2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-30',
               '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31',
               '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

My ultimate goal, for my project is to get something like this:

```
[['2018-01-01','2018-01-31'],['2018-02-01','2018-02-28'],...]
```

Trying to find the most efficient way to execute this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution : [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists, and iterate, using the [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html) to get the dates as strings

```
  [[start.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    end.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    ]
   for start,end 
   in zip(start_of_month_dates, 
          end_of_month_dates)
  ]

  [['2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'],
   ['2018-02-01', '2018-02-28'],
   ['2018-03-01', '2018-03-31'],
   ['2018-04-01', '2018-04-30'],
   ['2018-05-01', '2018-05-31'],
   ...]
```

Comment: After I posted I made a function... not recognizing that I did exactly this. I wanted a one liner, not a function... so I could have just ran the innards of my function and had been done... brain fart. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my approach is efficient but I belive you could do:

```py
start_of_month_dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2021-01-01' , freq='1M')-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
end_of_month_dates = pd.date_range('2018-02-01', '2021-02-01' , freq='1M')-pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)

dates = []
for i in range(len(end_of_month_dates)):
...     dates.append([start_of_month_dates[i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), end_of_month_dates[i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")])

print(dates)
[['2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'], ['2018-02-01', '2018-02-28'], 
 ['2018-03-01', '2018-03-31'], ['2018-04-01', '2018-04-30'],
 ['2018-05-01', '2018-05-31'], ['2018-06-01', '2018-06-30'],
 ['2018-07-01', '2018-07-31'], ['2018-08-01', '2018-08-31'],
 ['2018-09-01', '2018-09-30'], ['2018-10-01', '2018-10-31'],
 ['2018-11-01', '2018-11-30'], ['2018-12-01', '2018-12-31'],
 ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'], ['2019-02-01', '2019-02-28'],
 ['2019-03-01', '2019-03-31'], ['2019-04-01', '2019-04-30'],
 ['2019-05-01', '2019-05-31'], ['2019-06-01', '2019-06-30'],
 ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-31'], ['2019-08-01', '2019-08-31'],
 ['2019-09-01', '2019-09-30'], ['2019-10-01', '2019-10-31'],
 ['2019-11-01', '2019-11-30'], ['2019-12-01', '2019-12-31'],
 ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-31'], ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-29'],
 ['2020-03-01', '2020-03-31'], ['2020-04-01', '2020-04-30'],
 ['2020-05-01', '2020-05-31'], ['2020-06-01', '2020-06-30'],
 ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-31'], ['2020-08-01', '2020-08-31'],
 ['2020-09-01', '2020-09-30'], ['2020-10-01', '2020-10-31'],
 ['2020-11-01', '2020-11-30'], ['2020-12-01', '2020-12-31']]
```

Let me know if this helps! :D